# First-In-First-Out Stock trading - calculate cumulative P/L

Tags: sql-server, fifo

I want a sql-server query to calculate cumulative P/L on stock trading (FIFO based calculation).

Input table :

| EXECTIME | share_name | Quantity | Price | Buy/Sell |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-01-01 12:25 | abc | 100 | 100 | B |
| 2013-01-01 12:26 | abc | 10 | 102 | S |
| 2013-01-01 12:27 | abc | 10 | 102 | S |
| 2013-01-01 12:28 | abc | 10 | 95 | S |
| 2013-01-01 12:29 | abc | 10 | 99 | S |
| 2013-01-01 12:30 | abc | 10 | 105 | S |
| 2013-01-01 12:31 | abc | 100 | 102 | B |
| 2013-01-01 12:32 | abc | 150 | 101 | S |

OUTPUT :

| EXECTIME | Cumualative P/L | Winning Streak | Lossing Streak |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-01-01 12:26 | 20 | 1 | 0 |
| 2013-01-01 12:27 | 40 | 1 | 0 |
| 2013-01-01 12:28 | -10 | 0 | 1 |
| 2013-01-01 12:29 | -20 | 0 | 2 |
| 2013-01-01 12:30 | 30 | 1 | 0 |
| 2013-01-01 12:32 | -20 | 0 | 1 |

Explanation :

1st row - 10 shares sold at 102 which were purchased at 100. So profit = (102-100) * 10 = 20

6th row - 150 shares sold at 101,
50 were purchased at 100 - 1st row( 50 already sold above, 50 left)
100 were purchaed at 102 - 7th row

150 * 101 - [(50 * 100)+(100 * 102)] = -50
cumaltive p/l = 30 + (-50) = -20

Winning streak - 1 for positive

Lossing streak - 1,2,... for continuous loss. reset again after profit

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. I have removed the conflicting tags; please retag the RDBMS you are actually using and **only** that RDBMS. Thanks.

Comment: Why did you undo the formatting... -_-

Comment: Thanks @Larnu for the edit. I would be so thankful if you can help me with the problem statement.

Comment: I'm not a MySQL user, I'm afraid. It was your incorrect [tag:sql-server] tag that brought the question to my attention (and why you should ensure you tag properly).

Comment: @Larnu I actually need it for sql-server.

Comment: If you need to do this for an actual stock trading system, then I can assure you that this is vastly more complicated than you think. But this is not a free code-writing service and allocating cost has been discussed previously and in different forums. Your first action is to do your research and search the internet.